# Compression decompression documentation

Tags: compression

How and from where do I start learning about Compression/decompression/encoding/decoding methods and algos. aven't found any systematically organised resources. All suggestions welcome!

Comment: so what have you searched for ?

Comment: I've searched for mathematical formulation behind methods like AES, symmetric, assymetric encryption/decryption, cryptography and pseudo codes for the same.

Comment: So what does AES, symmetric, asymmetric encryption/decryption, cryptography and pseudo codes have to do with Data compression?  Those  might be something  to apply after data compression.  A Quick google Search on Data compression might be better:  https://www.google.com/search?q=data+compression+algorithms  and maybe you are looking more for stuff here : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A Google search for encryption algorithms https://www.google.com/search?q=encryption+algorithms

Comment: Ok thanks, I/m a information theory illiterate